# KNN, python: TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

My code works fine on a friends computer I do not understand why does it work on anaconda environment on my computer, please help. Is it a problem with python installation or with the code?

Both iris_train and iris_test data files look:

> Blockquote

```
Sepal Length    Sepal Width  Petal Length   Petal Width   classType    classNames

5.1             3.5          1.4            0.2          Iris-setosa        Iris-setosa
4.9             3            1.4            0.2          Iris-setosa        Iris-virginica
4.7             3.2          1.3            0.2          Iris-setosa        Iris-versicolor
```

> Blockquote

Receive following error when I run the code:

```
File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

File   "/Users/nadiastraton/Documents/workspacePython/02450Toolbox_Python/Thesis/Scripts/   Script_Results/KNN/KNN1.py", line 30, in <module>
classNames = list({name[0] for name in data_train['classNames']})

File "/Users/nadiastraton/Documents/workspacePython/02450Toolbox_Python/Thesis/Scripts/  Script_Results/KNN/KNN1.py", line 30, in <setcomp>
classNames = list({name[0] for name in data_train['classNames']})

TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Receive following errors, when I try to access run file ('KNN1') from the terminal:

```
File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1,    in <module>
from matplotlib.pylab import *
File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1131, in <module>
rcParams = rc_params()
File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 975, in rc_params
return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1100, in rc_params_from_file
config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1018, in _rc_params_in_file
with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1000, in _open_file_or_url
encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
return _parse_localename(localename)
File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

My code is:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from pylab import figure, ylabel, xlabel,hold, xticks,yticks, show, title,    plot, imshow, colorbar
import pandas as pd


data_train  =pd.read_excel('iris_train.xlsx')
data_test =pd.read_excel('iris_test.xlsx')

X_train =data_train.as_matrix(columns=['Sepal Length', 'Sepal Width'])
X_test =data_test.as_matrix(columns=['Sepal Length', 'Sepal Width'])

y_train =data_train.as_matrix(columns=['classType'])
y_test =data_test.as_matrix(columns=['classType'])

# attributeNames = [name[0] for name in data['attributeNames'].squeeze()]
classNames = list({name[0] for name in data_train['classNames']})
N, M = X_train.shape
C = len(classNames)

# K-nearest neighbors
K=2

# Distance metric (corresponds to 2nd norm, euclidean distance).
# You can set dist=1 to obtain manhattan distance (cityblock distance).
dist=2

# Fit classifier and classify the test points
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=K, p=dist);
knn.fit(X_train, y_train);
y_est = knn.predict(X_test);

# Plot the training data points (color-coded) and test data points.
figure(1);
hold(True);
styles = ['.b', '.r', '.g']
# import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
for c in range(C):
class_mask = (y_train==c)
plot(X_train[class_mask], X_train[class_mask], styles[c])

# Plot the classfication results
styles = ['ob', 'or', 'og']
for c in range(C):
class_mask = (y_est==c)
plot(X_test[class_mask,0], X_test[class_mask,1], styles[c], markersize=10)
plot(X_test[class_mask,0], X_test[class_mask,1], 'kx', markersize=8)
title('Synthetic data classification - KNN');

# Compute and plot confusion matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test.ravel(), y_est);
accuracy = 100*cm.diagonal().sum()/cm.sum(); error_rate = 100-accuracy;
figure(2);
imshow(cm, cmap='binary', interpolation='None');
colorbar()
xticks(range(C));
yticks(range(C));
xlabel('Predicted class'); ylabel('Actual class');
title('Confusion matrix (Accuracy: {0}%, Error Rate: {1}%)'.format(accuracy,   error_rate));

 show()
```

Comment: Your `name` variable appears to be _float_ (instead of _string_). When you try to index/slice it (`name[0]`), you get this error. Add a `print name` line before the line: `classNames = list({name[0] for name in data_train['classNames']})` in order to test that. I guess the files are not read as you are expecting.

Comment: thanks @CristiFati, when I call on `print(data_train['classNames'])` I get as expected exact output as in the file iris_train, so not sure how to fix the problem still: `0               Iris-setosa
1       Iris-virginica
2      Iris-versicolor
3                  NaN
4                  NaN
5                  NaN
6                  NaN`

Comment: Sorry, I rushed with my previous comment: the `print` statement as I suggested doesn't work, because `name` is undefined at that point. In order to debug further, add the following lines: `tmp = data_train['classNames']`, `print type(tmp), tmp`, `print type(tmp[0]), tmp[0]`

Comment: @CristiFati  Following commands: `tmp = data_train['classNames']`

`print(tmp)` prints the full list

`print(tmp[0:4])`  prints from line 0 to 4, therefore column header, 3 lines with classes and empty line :  `Name: classNames,` `dtype: object`
`0        Iris-setosa`
`1     Iris-virginica`
`2    Iris-versicolor`
`3                NaN`   Therefore variable className prints object, not sure why float is a problem